# Can pandas work with multiple result sets?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, multiple-resultsets

Assuming the database and driver support nextset(), is there a way for me to use pandas to process multiple sets?  I've only been working with pandas for a few days, so I'm not sure what I expect it to look like.  My current workflow is `df = pd.read_sql(sql_statement, db)`, slicing up `df` into sections as I process them consecutively.  If I could somehow use `cursor.nextset()` instead, I would be able to simplify the stored proc significantly.

Comment: what does `cursor.nextset()` return? a list of rows? how many?

Comment: [cursor.nextset()](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#nextset) returns a true value if there's another set, else None.  It causes subsequent fetch* methods to pull from the next set in the list.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627048/pandas-io-sql-and-stored-procedure-with-multiple-result-sets