# Pandas IO SQL and stored procedure with multiple result sets

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, stored-procedures, pandasql

So I have a stored proc on a local sql server, this returns multiple data sets / tables

Normally, in python / pyodbc I would use

```
cursor.nextset()
subset1 = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.nextset()
subset2 = cursor.fetchall()
```

I wish to make use of the ps.io.sql.read_sql and return the stored procedure with multiple result sets into dataframes, however I can not find anything that references how to move the cursor along and get more information before closing things off.

```
import pandas as ps

query = "execute raw.GetDetails @someParam = '118'"
conn = myConnection() #connection,cursor

results = ps.io.sql.read_sql(query, con=conn[0])

results.head()

conn[1].close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(username, password, server, database_name))
connection = engine.connect().connection
cursor = self.connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('call storedProcName(%s, %s, ...)', params)

# Results set 1
column_names = [col[0] for col in cursor.description] # Get column names from MySQL

df1_data = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    df1_data.append({name: row[i] for i, name in enumerate(column_names)})

# Results set 2
cursor.nextset()
column_names = [col[0] for col in cursor.description] # Get column names from MySQL

df2_data = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    df2_data.append({name: row[j] for j, name in enumerate(column_names)})

cursor.close()

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1_data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_data)
```

**Edit:** I've updated the code here to avoid having to manually specify the column names.

Note that the original question only specifies a "local SQL server", not a specific kind of SQL server. This answer works with MySQL, but I haven't tested it with any other variety.

Comment: Whilst this should work, it introduces a sqlalchemy dependency and also seems to be referencing a mysql server?

Comment: `sqlalchemy` is required for importing data into Pandas in the standard manner (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries), so rather than connecting to the database differently just for multiple result sets, for most people it will make sense to just use `sqlalchemy`. However, it should be trivial to use the methodology in this answer with a different method of connecting to the database. Regarding "referencing a mysql server", please see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#database-urls.

Comment: do you know, how can i achieve same behaviour using pandas.read_sql function?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59149457/does-pandas-support-reading-data-from-multiple-tables-into-a-dataframe

Comment: For better performance I would just create the dataframe for each data set like this: `df1 = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(),columns=["col_name1","col_name2"])`